# Calling Method adding input

Tags: java, methods

I'm writing a program in which the user inputs 10 numbers, and they are added together as they are input and then the average is displayed. So far I have this, and I'm stuck as to what to put in the loop body to achieve this. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputMethod
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int loop_Value;
    int end_Value = 10;
    for(loop_Value =0; loop_Value < end_Value; loop_Value++)
    {
        readInteger();

    }
}

private static int readInteger()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        scan.next();
        System.out.println ("Bad input. Enter an integer");
    }
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    {
        return input;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: So waiting for what? I'm sure you could do it on your own.

Comment: Please be sure to mark the correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an integer value, sum. In the loop body put

```
sum += readInteger();
```

At the end

```
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Then because the amount of numbers are fixed.

```
System.out.println("The average is " + (sum / end_Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only read the input: it lack the memorization of single number returned by *readInteger*

This is a working code *horrible-style*, not compliant with the Oracle/Sun guidelines.

```
public class InputMethod {

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int endValue = 10;

        InputMethod inputMethod = new InputMethod();
        for (int loop_Value = 0; loop_Value < endValue; loop_Value++) {
            int number=inputMethod.readInteger();/*storage the input*/

            inputMethod.numbers.add(number);
        }
        int sum=0;
        for (int loop_Value = 0; loop_Value < inputMethod.numbers.size(); loop_Value++) {
            sum=sum+inputMethod.numbers.get(loop_Value); /*partial sum*/
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of "+inputMethod.numbers+"= "+sum);
        System.out.println("Average of "+inputMethod.numbers+"= "+(double)(sum/inputMethod.numbers.size()));

    }

    private int readInteger() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
            scan.next();
            System.out.println("Bad input. Enter an integer");
        }
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        {

            return input;
        }

    }

}
```

Some observation:

- the variable's names doesn't have the *_*; you can insert him only if the name is not understable;
- is better not to declare the variable of *for* loop outside the cycle: every variable has to have the mininum scope into program;
- *System.out.println ("Bad input. Enter an integer");* should to be *System.err.println ("Bad input. Enter an integer");*: sysout for normal message, syserr for error.

It's better to know and apply the right conventions by learning a language; after it's more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int sum=0;
    for(loop_Value =0; loop_Value < end_Value; loop_Value++)
    {
      sum += (readInteger());
    }
    double avg = sum/end_value;
```